# lastChild (or lastElementChild) undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So recently I began playing around with the DOM stuff, which is obviously important to know. Tried to do a simple script that paints the last element of a `div`
There's HTML. AFAIK the last child element of the `div` is that `span` element near the bottom

```
<div id="java">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
<span>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</span>
</div>
```

There's the js line that paints the last child blue

```
document.getElementById("java").lastChild.innerHTML.style.color = "blue";
```

So the problem is that I'm getting `Cannot set property 'color' of undefined` error even when I use `lastElementChild` like I was advised before.
Is there anything I missed? I mean, of course there is, but what is that and how can I get this to work using `lastChild`?

Comment: `style` is on `lastChild`, not on `innerHTML`. `document.getElementById("java").lastChild` does exist. The error indicates that `style` is undefined, not `lastChild`.

Comment: Thanks! `document.getElementById("java").lastChild.style.color = "blue";` worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lastElementChild` to get the last child of an element

```
document.getElementById("java").lastElementChild.style.color= "blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var myContainer = document.getElementById('my-container');
var lastElement = myContainer.lastElementChild;
lastElement.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0,0,255)';
```

**Example:**

```js
var myContainer = document.getElementById('my-container');
var lastElement = myContainer.lastElementChild;
lastElement.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0,0,255)';
```

```css
#my-container div {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 24px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div id="my-container">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I used `document.getElementById("java").lastChild.style.color = "blue";` so the problem is resolved, thanks for help! :)